# Encoding Defaulting to ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby

I have the following file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
a = 1 << 7
puts a.chr.encoding
```

This gives me back `ASCII-8BIT`. Why doesn't this give back `UTF-8` and I would expect?

Comment: because ascii chars 0->127 and utf-8 chars 0->127 are identical. utf8 **IS** 7bit ascii when only considering those first 128 characters. utf8 only comes into play when the high bit in the byte it set, which is utf8's "escape" char to signal the start of a multibyte sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chr` has a encoding parameter, defaulting to US-ASCII, when char is `< 0x80` and ASCII-8BIT for `< 0xff` (there UTF is identical to ASCII):

```
65.chr.encoding                   # => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
128.chr.encoding                  # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
255.chr.encoding                  # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
256.chr.encoding                  # => RangeError: 256 out of char range

Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
65.chr.encoding                   # => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
255.chr.encoding                  # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
256.chr.encoding                  # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>

65.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).encoding  # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
128.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
500.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Note that [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines 128 characters. `chr` therefore returns `US-ASCII` for 7-bit codes (0..127) and `ASCII-8BIT` for 8-bit codes (128..255) by default.